# После установки БД не могу подключится с созданым пользователем

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

Установил на свой ПК Oracle БД 18c Express Edition.

Подключаюсь через SQL*Plus и создаю пользователя:

```
Copyright <c> 1982, 2018, Oracle,    All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system 
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Sat Jun 13 2020 23:11:26 +06:00 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production 
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; 

Session altered.

SQL> create user INFA_D0M identified by INFA_D0M; 

User created.

SQL> grant dba to INFA_D0M;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn INFA_DOM/INFA_DOM;
Connected.
SQL> _
```

Теперь, в Informatica Powercenter (версии 9.6.1), когда нужно настроить БД для хранилища конфигурации домена, выбираю тип базы данных - Oracle, и ввожу:

- Database user ID: созданного пользователя и пароль
- Database adress: localhost:1521
- Database service name: orcl

Далее, пробую подключиться, но выводит сообщение:

> The connection failed.
> Correct the database connection information and test the connection again.

Не знаю, что делать с этим. И через SQL Server пробовал подключаться, выходит та же история.

Kак решить проблему?

---

**Дополнительная информация**

Вот, что дала следующая команда:

```
C:\> lsnrctl services
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Uersion 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 14-JUN-2020 09:56:33

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.    All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))) 
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc"  has   1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 
         LOCAL SERVER 
The command completed successfully
```

Содержимое файла listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\User\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\User\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\User\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Содержимое файла tnsnames.ora::

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\User\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что сервис называется orcl? Как  вы к SQL*Plus подключились, покажите.

Comment: я ниже приложил скриншоты подключения к SQL*Plus, нет не уверен, что так называется, содержимое файла tnsnamas.ora тоже приложил, там название сервиса XEPDB1, но с этим значением тоже не работает

Comment: Вы забыли собственно БД запустить. Выполните в SQL*Plus: `show pdbs`.

Comment: И пожалуйста, дополняйте вопрос кнопкой править. Ответ удалите. Информацию предоставляйте по возмоожности в текстовом виде, а не картинками.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не знал, что можно дополнять вопросы, спасибо Вам!
Вот, что показала команда show pdbs
   2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
   3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO

Comment: _я попробовал задать Service name как orcl.PC.com_ - это неверно. Ваш сервис: xepdb1, но он по видимому пока не зарегистрирован. Попробуйте: lsnrctl status

Comment: а как его зарегистрировать?

Comment: В двух словах не расскажешь, но нормально он должен автоматически регистрироваться. Если вы будете игнорировать мои уточнения в комментарии, а задавать другие вопросы, то мы далеко не уйдём.  Ещё раз, попробуйте: lsnrctl status

Comment: простите, я попробовал, тут все норм:
Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "bc794fb7d69c414c93d9e065cfd11dc6" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

Comment: Так у вас всё работает, только сервис называется XEPDB, а не XEPDB1.

Comment: да, но все равно подключение не проходит:(

Comment: Попробуйте: sqlplus -l sys/<pass>@localhost/xepdb as sysdba.  _подключение не проходит_ - всегда пишите причину, вам же не выводит в ответ: "Сегодня не подключаю".

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию имя сервиса состоит из двух частей и выглядит примерно так: `orcl.example.com`.

1. Имя БД (`db_name`) - часто совпадает с именем инстанции БД, например *orcl*.
2. Домена (`db_domain`) - по умолчанию имя домена машины, на которой установлена БД.

Посммотреть, какие сервисы действительно известны прослушивателю можно следующей командой (ниже приведён сокращённый пример вывода):

```
$ lsnrctl services

Service "orcl.example.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:117 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: имя моего компьютера PC, значит orcl.PC.com?

Comment: К голосующим: воздержитесь пожалуйста от голосования. ТС дополнит свой   вопрос и этот ответ будет переработан.

Comment: @Данил Интересует полное имя вашего компьютера:  `net config workstation | findstr /C:"Full Computer name"`.

Comment: посмотрел полное имя и есть PC

Comment: @Данил Хорошо. Теперь проверьте вопрос после переработки, всё соответствует истине. Оставте комментарий, если что-то не так.

Comment: спасибо попробую и дам Вам знать!

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало, осталась та же проблема.

Comment: А что вы пробовали, вроде я ничего не предлагал? Я попросил проверить вопрос после переработки. Попробуйте: lsnrctl status

Comment: я попробовал задать Service name как orcl.PC.com